# Tableview scrolling Checked button image automatically hide

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am developing IOS App. Using tableview to expand and collpase. Add Button on TableviewCell for check or Uncheck. Example I am Selected First Row button. Than scrolling tableview and select last header to last row  button selected. Than again scrolling and see first index selected button image hidden.

```
Code..
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    if (self.sectionNames.count > 0) {
        _tableView.backgroundView = nil;
        return self.sectionNames.count;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        NSMutableArray *arrayOfItems = [self.sectionItems objectAtIndex:section];
        return arrayOfItems.count;

}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (self.sectionNames.count) {
        return [self.sectionNames objectAtIndex:section];
    }
    return @"";
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section; {
    return 44.0;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // recast your view as a UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
  //  header.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:@"#484848"];
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    header.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    header.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro SemiBold" size:15.0];
    UIImageView *viewWithTag = [self.view viewWithTag:kHeaderSectionTag + section];
    if (viewWithTag) {
        [viewWithTag removeFromSuperview];
    }
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 //   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = nil;
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
//    for(UIView *subview in [cell subviews]) {
//        [subview removeFromSuperview];
//    }

    UILabel *sectionLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35.0f, 12.0f, 120.0f, 20.f)];
    sectionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    sectionLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    sectionLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    sectionLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
    [cell addSubview:sectionLabel];

    NSArray *section = [self.sectionItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    sectionLabel.text = [section objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(5.0f, 9.0f, 25.0f, 25.0f)];
    button.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor colorWithRed:244.0f/255.0f
                                               green:129.0f/255.0f
                                                blue:32.0f/255.0f
                                               alpha:1.0] CGColor];
    [button.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
    button.tag = indexPath.section;

    NSString *data = [section objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //For Selected Fliters
    for (int i=0; i<[filterArray count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [filterArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *fliterTickValue = [dict valueForKey:@"filterValue"];
        if ([fliterTickValue isEqualToString:data]) {
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tick.png"];
            [button setImage: img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else{
            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
            [button setImage: img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(fliterFields:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [cell addSubview:button];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Imho, your calls [cell addSubview:] is not correct. In case that cell is re-used, it will already have those subviews and resulting layout of your cell is not quite clear.

I suggest you to design your cell in xib and load it when needed. Then your cellForRowAtIndexPath becomes simpler and deals mostly with data populating. Subviews you don't need at the moment can be hidden and so on. If you need code and design example - let me know.